# Time as key into SQL causes error

Tags: java, android, sql

I'm trying to fix a bug regarding SQL (used in Android), the statement basically looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO log (time, message) VALUES (datetime('now'),<a_message>);
```

The "datetime(now)" seems to be the key into the database, and the problem regarding it is that it can be called 2 times within one millisecond. If that happens, an error in SQL will be thrown since the key is not unique.

I could use REPLACE into, but that would overwrite one (or more) entry's. I could also check the error code, sleep some time and try again. I'm just wondering if anyone have a better solution for this problem? I'm not very experienced with SQL.

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you use an auto-increment field for the key?

Comment: @BeRecursive I not really allowed to redesign the tables, I can only give input to the guys responsible for it. If I could it would probably be the best solution.

Comment: Well then as mentioned in the best answer you are stuck with a bit of a mess. What if you generate (hopefully) random hashes for the key and then prepend log messages with the time? This will vastly slow down queries for logs but presumably this isn't a time critical action?

Answer (score 4):

You should be much more hesitant to use the datetime as a primary key anyway because of the wild and wooly world of timezones, leapseconds, and lots of other things that will surprise you.  There is absolutely no guarantee that `a1 = datetime('now')` is always less than or equal to the next invocation of `a2 = datetime('now')`

Read this article, about 1/3 the way down he starts talking about dates, times, and timezones.  This should convince you that you should not be trying to do what you are asking for in this question:

https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/11/02/omg-ponies-aka-humanity-epic-fail.aspx

If I wanted a quick and dirty hack work around, I would put the insert into a while loop and catch the error when the insert failed, and then try again 1 millisecond later.  This is bad, and is like leaving a huge mess in the bedroom, but sometimes it is necessary because redesigning the table to have a sensible primary key would take too long.

However, if you do this, be prepared for the code to be sitting in that while loop, trying and waiting patiently for tens of milliseconds, and when it finally does find an open slot, it doesn't do what you expect because it appears BEFORE another entry that occurred in the future (which was actually in the past).  Thinking about that makes my head hurt.

Answer (score 2):

Simple.  You don't use  time value as a primary key.  Instead create the table with one extra column that automatically increments, a surrogate key.

```
CREATE TABLE log (
  id         INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  time       REAL,
  message    TEXT
)
```

Your existing INSERT should then work fine.

If you need to optimise retrieval of records based on the time field, you can still do that; just add an index for that field.  Just be aware, if you use joins on that field, having a specific time does not equate to a single specific record.

Comment: Thanks, great answer, but I'm not allowed to redesign the tables :)